# How to get the inner control in a ControlValueAccessor in the correct validation satet in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material2

We started with implementation of a component library for our Angular (version 12 at the moment) project.

At the moment we implement the first component as a blueprint. The component should encapsulate a Material input (`matInput`) with label, mat-errors, some validators etc. so that the developer just needs to write s.th. like

```html
<our-input max-length="5" required label="fancy field" [formControlName]="fancyField">
```

to get a fully designed input field. Btw. I'm aware that mixing validations from `FormControl` and template should not be done, but that is only for the sake of the example; in real life the validation will be defined by the component like a datepicker.

At the moment our template is realy simple:

```html
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
  <input
    matInput
    [formControl]="formControl"
    (input)="onInputChange($event)"
    (blur)="onInputBlur()"
  />
  <mat-error *ngFor="let error of outerControl.errors | keyvalue">
    <ng-container [ngSwitch]="error.key">
      <ng-container *ngSwitchCase="'required'">
        Field required error
      </ng-container>
...
    </ng-container>
  </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

We are stuck at the part with the validation. If the validation happens only for the "outer control" (the control `fancyField` in the example) the inner `matInput` neither get the styling nor not show the validation errors because it simply does not know that it is invalid.

Because we register some validators in a similar way Netanel Basal described in his blog post [Adding Integrated Validation to Custom Form Controls in Angular](https://netbasal.com/adding-integrated-validation-to-custom-form-controls-in-angular-dc55e49639ae) we already have access to the outer `NgControl`:

```js
  constructor(@Self() private ngControl: NgControl) {
    controlDirective.valueAccessor = this;
  }
```

We already tried to call the outer validators as an inner validator

```js
 this.formControl.addValidators((control) => this.ngControl.control.validator?.(control));
 // the same for asyncValidators?
```

or inspired by Christian Lüdemann's post [Form validation with ControlValueAccessor](https://christianlydemann.com/form-validation-with-controlvalueaccessor/) to assign the outer form control to the inner form control on view-init

```js
public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // syncing with validators on host element
    this.formControl = this.ngControl.control as FormControl;
}
```

but both methods trigger the validators twice. Additionally I have a strange feeling about connecting a FormControl to two template controls.

Here is an example at StckBlitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-swiydl

I guess there some other solutions, too.

I already thought about trying to mirror the outer state but did not find any feasible way to have change detection for properties of an object which is not in a template. The only solution I could found was to create an inner component to bind properties of `this.ngControl.control` but the felt strange, too.

Which way would you got or is there any better way?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are injecting `NgControl` it’s your job to set up the `NgControl` correctly with the right value accessor and validators. You've set up the value accessor correctly. For the latter part you can do something like:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   const control = this.ngControl.control;
   const validators = control.validator
      ? [control.validator, Validators.required]
      : Validators.required;
   control.setValidators(validators);
   control.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

Notice that in this snippet we don't replace validators, instead, we add the `required` validation to any existing validations.

Here is an updated [StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/custom-form-controls-demo-enhanced). Have a look at the `personal.component.ts`. It's a composite CVA, but the logic would be pretty much the same in your case.

I also wrote [this article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-custom-form-controls-nested-form-groups-made-easy-2ac09e91cf67?sk=06cf6f37eeeae34b8f02fd6c5080f759) about custom form components. Although it does not involve a Material input, it may still be helpful to you.

Finally, you can check [this guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control) on custom form controls, from the official Material website.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser but I am afrtaid that your anwser do not fit to my question.

My question is how to get the the control in the same error-state (and if possible with error messages) like the outer control. At the moment my best bet is adding a custom ErrorStateMatcher to return outer control's `control.invalid` value and displaying the error messages from the outer control.

Comment: @Kleidersack After re-reading your post, I'm a bit confused with your StackBlitz. Why are you setting validators to your `FormControl` in the  `app.component.ts`? Do you need to set validations conditionally from both components?

Comment: I am afraid I choose a too generic example. Let's imagine that we are talking about a time-input. The time-input will just validate whether the text in the text field is a valid time. The form which will use the control will define further validations like whether it is required only during office hours etc.

Comment: finally I settled with `ErrorStateMatcher` solution. As you offered this solution I would like to mark your answer is the answer. Would you mind to post it as answer so I can mark it? Sorry for long wait...